# how to create custom node in knime?

Tags: knime

I have added all the plugins of Knime in Eclipse and I want to create my Own custom node. but I am not able to understand how to pass the data from one node to another node.

I saw one node which has been provided by the Knime itself which is " File Reader "  node. Now I want the source code of this node or jar file for this node But I am not able to find it out.

I am searching with the similar name in eclipse plugin folder but still I didn't get it.

Can someone please tell me how to pass the data from one node to another node and how to identify the classes or jar for any node given by knime and source code also.

Comment: Please delete your email from the post. Stackoverflow answers are not given via email and leaving it here, will simply cause a lot of spam being sent to it. You may also tag your question with "Eclipse" such that people are able to find it.

Comment: https://tech.knime.org/developers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is a standard datatable, then you need to subclass NodeModel, with a call to the supertype constructor:

```
public MyNodeModel(){
     //One incoming table, one outgoing table
     super(1,1);
}
```

You need to override the default `#execute(BufferedDataTable[] inData, ExecutionContext exec)` method - this is where the meat of the node work is done and the output table created.  Ideally, if your input and output table have a one-to-one row mapping then use a `ColumnRearranger` class (because this reduces disk IO considerably, and if you need it, allows simple parallelisation of your node), otherwise your execute method needs to iterate through the incoming datatable and generate an output table.

The `#configure(DataTableSpec[] inSpecs)` method needs to be implemented to at the least provide a spec for the output table if this can be determined before the node is executed (it normally can, and this allows downstream nodes also to be configures, but the 'Transpose' node is an example of a node which cannot do so).

There are various other methods which you also need to implement, but in some cases these will be empty methods.

In addition to the NodeModel, you need to implement some other classes too - a NodeFactory, optionally a NodeSettingsPane and optionally a NodeView.

In Eclipse you can view the sources for many nodes, and also the KNIME community 'book' pages all have a link to their source code.  Take a look at https://tech.knime.org/developer-guide and https://tech.knime.org/developer/example for a step-by-step guide.  Also, questions to the knime forums (including a developer forum) generally get rapid responses - and KNIME run a Developer Training Course a few times a year if you want to spend a few days learning more.  And last but not least, it is worth familiarising yourself with the noding guidelines which describe the best practice of how your node should behave

Answer (score 0):

Source code for KNIME nodes are now available on [git hub](https://github.com/knime/knime-core).

Alternatively you can check under your project>plugin dependencies>knime-base.jar>org.knime.base.node.io.filereader for file reader source code in eclipse KNIME SDK.

Knime-base.jar will be added to your project by default  when created with KNIME SDK.